# mocha test failing with " MongoError: server sockets closed"

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mocha.js

My mocha tests are failing with:

> MongoError: server XXXX sockets closed

I have a workaround how to fix them:

```
const https = require('https');
const server = https.createServer(..);

close() {
        mongoose.disconnect(); // <-------- I will comment this line
        this.server.close();
    };
```

I would comment out the line `mongoose.disconnect();` and my test suite starts working. I would like to clean up after my tests too. Each of my test files recreates server and starts from the scratch. It seems like the error appears because there needs to be some 'waiting' before the next test file executes.

How can I correct this error?

Comment: you can use Mocha hooks for cleaning up before and after tests: https://mochajs.org/#hooks

Comment: Thx Flame. Currently, I don't have any active js project. Post the answer and if people agree it's working I'll accept the answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

### Solution - Captain Hook to the rescue!

If I understand correctly, you wish to startup and cleanup your server after the tests. You also have a series of repetitive tasks you need to do before and after each test.

Mocha has the perfect solution for you: *Say hello to Mr. Hook!*

[image: captain_hook]

Mocha hooks are functions that you can run both before all tests, after all tests, or before each test  and after each test:

- https://mochajs.org/#hooks

The documentation is pretty complete and I really do recommend it. I your case however, since you are dealing with databases, you probably will be dealing with `async` hooks.

Sounds complex? Don't worry!

This is how normal `sync` hooks work:

```
describe('hooks', function() {

  before(function() {
    // runs before all tests in this block
  });

  after(function() {
    // runs after all tests in this block
  });

  beforeEach(function() {
    // runs before each test in this block
  });

  afterEach(function() {
    // runs after each test in this block
  });

  //tests
  it("This is a test", () => {
      assert.equal(1, 1);
  });

});
```

`async` hooks only have one difference: they have a parameter `done`, which is called once your task is finished. Lets assume that we are setting up a DB that takes 1.5 seconds to setup. We want to do this before all the tests, and we only want to do it once.

Let's assume this is our `listen` function from our DB:

```
const listen = callback => {
    setTimeout(callback, 1500);
};
```

So after 1.5 seconds, it calls the callback function signalizing it is ready for action.

Now lets see how we would make an `async` hook:

```
describe('hooks', function() {

  let myDB;
  before( done => {
      myDB = newDB();
      myDB(done);
  });

  //tests
});
```

And that's it! Hope it helps!

Comment: Funniest answer. ;)